# Troubleshooting Imagemagick install

Tags: macos, homebrew

Context:

- OS: MacOS HighSierra
- Installation Method:

  `brew install imagemagick`

Console Returned:

```
==> Installing dependencies for imagemagick: libxml2, itstool, libffi, pcre, glib, docbook, docbook-xsl, libyaml, ruby, asciidoctor, gnu-getopt, xmlto, shared-mime-info, x265, libheif, liblqr, libtool, jasper, libomp and libraw
==> Installing imagemagick dependency: libxml2
==> Patching
==> Applying configure-big_sur.diff
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 8188 (offset -545 lines).
==> Applying libxml2-python3-unicode-errors.patch
patching file python/libxml.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1621 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1638 (offset 1 line).
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.14_2 --with-history --with-icu --without-python --without-lzma
==> make install
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass
```

Error Returned:

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass
```

What is the next step to diagnosing / corrective action?  Any insight as to the root cause of the problem is appreciated: thank you.

Any constructive edit / feedback questions is appreciated

Comment: Looks like problems patching `libxml2`. I would make a backup, then uninstall `libxml2` and reinstall it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell. Thanks for replying.  Are you suggesting executing `brew remove libxml2` from the command line?   If yes,  please consider making this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**homebrew** appears to be having difficulty patching and upgrading from an old version of `libxml2`.

Personally, I would just remove it and try a fresh reinstallation:

```
brew remove --force libxml2
brew install libxml2
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Still getting `NoMethodError: undefined method '/' for nil:NilClass` when attempting to install libxml2 on High Sierra (10.13.6).